# How to handle more efficient GUI windows?

Tags: java, javafx

I found that Im using duplicated code when i create and show GUI windows. Im trying to find an elegant way that should make my code more clear because my application has multiple GUI window forms.
Could any design pattern apply to this kind of problem?

Comment: Show an example here please.

Comment: Well i use the typical way of javafx. Load the fxml, set the parent and then setup the stage.

Comment: Can you load the fxml and set the controller ? This way you could use one controller for many views, and you can also fragment your views to re-use those fragments in a "root" fxml. Would that work ?

Comment: @Jacks "Use one controller for many views" - that would not work in the vast majority of scenarios.

Comment: I think in JavaFX you can use only one controller for each FXML.

Comment: Just move the duplicate code to utility methods. No design patterns required at all....

Comment: @James_D In my case, I have many forms used in different contexts but with the same logic. I can assign a controller, let's say `CtrlForm` to the `ViewFormA` and `ViewFormB`, but maybe my case is a special case (the differences are, for example, related to the persistence used by `CtrlForm`).

Comment: But if you use the same controller for different forms, any `@FXML`-injection will not work correctly, as the values in the controller will be replaced each time you load a new fxml file... You need to have a one-one correspondence between controller instances and view instances, and you should have a different controller class for each FXML. Just do as @fabian says and move duplicate code to utility methods, or use inheritance. There is no need for a design pattern for this, it's just normal programming.

Comment: @James_D Yes, I understand what you are pointing out. Of course it is more than correct to move methods to utility methods, but I've got a special case where one controller can manage two fxml files (and files have the same fields, it is just the behaviour that changes) that's why. But I misunderstood the question at the beginning, that's why I proposed that. My bad, and thanks for pointing those points out !

Comment: @Jacks But even then it's still a mistake to use the same controller for different views. I can see using the same controller class for views from both FXML files in that (somewhat unusual) case, but using the same actual controller as you suggested would not be a good idea at all. But anyway, the actual question here is very unclear, and should be closed unless it is improved, imho.

Comment: @James_D I forgot to mention that my views are displayed only one at once, and there are not multiple-views displayed (as the question seems to declare). Of course, it there were multiple views displayed at once, then my solution would be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)You can use one `Stage`

2)Change between `Scenes`

3)Use fxml instead of plain java code

4)If the code is dublicate ,then define a general method with <5 parameters and return a form or result.

5)Read [this](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/) tutorial to learn about [MODEL-VIEWER-CONTROLLER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_Controller) pattern

Comment: Could i keep my main view on screen while i open another scenes? (Like settings view etc). I do not want to only have 1 window each time.

Comment: Yeah you can use a StackPane.http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html